# Are probability distributions with similar characteristic functions close to each other?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are real probability distributions with characteristic functions $\varphi_\mu$ and $\varphi_\nu$ that are close to each other in some metric (maybe $L^\infty$?). Can we say that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are close to each other in terms of some statistical distance? This is trivial when close means equal, but I'm unsure what can be said when we only have approximate equality. If it helps, we can restrict $\mu$ and $\nu$ to have compact support.

Answer (score 1):

If the metric is $L^1$, then it is a straightforward problem, if the density functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ exist, since $f_k(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-itx}\phi_k(t)dt$  Therefore $|f_1(x)-f_2(x)|\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\phi_1(t)-\phi_2(t)|dt$ (since $|e^{-itx}|=1)$  That is the density functions are near each other as $L^\infty$

Comment: Can you make this work without assuming that the densities exist?

Comment: It is harder because the formula for the inverse transform is $F_k(b)-F_k(a)=lim_{T\to \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-T}^T \frac{e^{-itb}-e^{-ita}}{it}\phi_k(t)dt$ so the inequality has to take into account $t$ near $0$, specifically a bound for $ \frac{e^{-itb}-e^{-ita}}{it}$.

Comment: I haven't worked it out fully, but I suspect $|b-a|$ would be the needed bound.

Comment: @herbsteinberg $|e^{iu}-e^{iv}| \leq |u-v|$ for $u, v$ real.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks - my guess is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are many bounds and this is an ongoing research problem. See for example

[Proximity of probability distributions in terms of Fourier–Stieltjes transforms (2016)](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Ebobko001/papers/2016_Rus.Math.Surveys_Smoothing.pdf)